# Point Cloud Visualization

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am trying to load and visualize a point cloud data by "addPointCloud" instruction.

```
    //***********
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);

if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> ("f.pcd", *cloud) == -1) 
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read the pcd file \n");
    return (-1);
  }
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer ("Simple Cloud Viewer");
viewer.setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
viewer.addPointCloud(cloud, "sample cloud");
    //***********
```

But instead of seeing my point cloud in a black background, only see a white backbround whithout any point cloud. Can any one tell me kindly where is my problem?

Comment: Have you tried zooming out? You may be looking at the cloud itself.

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your code

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
```

// do stuff

```
pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGB<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(cloud);
viewer.addPointCloud <pcl:PointXYZRGB> (cloud,rgb,"cloud1");
```

Depending on the viewpoint you have to zoom out.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer` window object has been created and you're currently looking at just the window... You would need to add .spin()

```
viewer.spin();
```